# 500 Internal Server Error - after update magento from 2.1.11 to 2.2.2

Tags: magento-2.1

I have been updating the magento version from 2.1.11 to 2.2.2 via composer.phar

update magento to 2.2.2 went correctly.

Then I run my store and see  error:
[500] Internal Server Error : Internal server error

```
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. Please contact the server administrator webmaster@brands.nazwa.pl and inform them of the time the error occured and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
```

in log file is:

```
[2018-01-30 17:54:27] main.CRITICAL: Asymmetric transaction rollback. {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Asymmetric transaction rollback. at /home/brandswearxv/ftp/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:316)"} []
```

Comment: Besides stating the log, what is your research showing? Have you tried what is suggested here? https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6465#issuecomment-251663620

Comment: You mean php bin/magento indexer:reindex and remove var folder? Yes I make this and still no work.

Comment: Yes, part of. And then, in more general terms when it comes to your research. I've not faced this issue, but it seems to be a non specific error message - and there are approaches mentioned on how to debug further.

Comment: What are the permission on the `generation` folder in the root of the site? I find that after installing 2.2 i have to change these every time, and when i don't i get a 500 error.

Comment: check php error log, not magento...

Comment: Where I can found php log error ? In var not available.